# I upgraded to Windows 10, and now I'm locked out of my computer

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I upgraded my laptop to Windows 10. The installation went without a hitch, however I now can't log on.

At the login screen, I enter my password and it says "Your device is offline. Please sign in with the last password used on this device" (I am).

It seems drivers for the WiFi card didn't survive, and I have no ethernet port. What do I do?

Comment: try this: http://www.kieranlane.com/2013/09/18/resetting-administrator-password-windows-2012/ The Windows + U is the Ease of Access icon on the login screen

Comment: Not a solution, but just in case you're actually using the wrong password: isn't there some Microsoft website on which you can log in using the same username and password? Just to confirm that you're really using the password you used last? Also, if you're using any funny characters: are you sure the keyboard layout is the one you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here wasn't that my password wasn't working. What also happened during the upgrade is that the keyboard layout reset to Eng-US. I have a UK keybaord layout, and my password (which contains non-alphanumeric characters) was coming up wrong. I only realised this when I clicked the 'show password' button.